# MySQL shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies on phpmyadmin

Tags: xampp

I know this is a common error , and I've actually looked at the other questions where people suggest to close skype or delete some file in XAMPP, but none of it actually worked for me. I've also noticed the other questions had completely different error logs than me. So I want to share my error log as well:

```
2020-03-19 10:42:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-03-19 10:42:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-03-19 10:42:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-03-19 10:42:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-03-19 10:42:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-03-19 10:42:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-03-19 10:42:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-03-19 10:42:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=49468
2020-03-19 10:42:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting a batch to recover 112 pages from redo log.
2020-03-19 10:42:28 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting final batch to recover 14 pages from redo log.
2020-03-19 10:42:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-03-19 10:42:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2020-03-19 10:42:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-03-19 10:42:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-03-19 10:42:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-03-19 10:42:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-03-19 10:42:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.3.16 started; log sequence number 1603190; transaction id 9
2020-03-19 10:42:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-03-19 10:42:29 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 200319 10:42:29
2020-03-19 10:42:29 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-03-19 10:42:29 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

To my understanding, I can't really get the error out of this log or am I missing something? What am I doing wrong? Starting Apache works fine but MySQL isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Because some tables was crash on mysql/data/ aria engine storage.

1. C:\xampp\xampp_shell.bat or command line on windows
2. Change directory into "C:\xampp\mysql\data\mysql"
3. Run "aria_chk -r *.MAI" until finished , after that restart Xampp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMWJb.png)